How to assign a class variable using the value obtained from JTextField in Java
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Test {
    private String textFieldValue;
        
    public Test() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame ();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();

        JLabel label = new JLabel("Enter your name:");
        JTextField textField = new JTextField(20);

        JButton button = new JButton("OK");

        panel.add(label);
        panel.add(textField);

        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
        frame.setSize(500, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE );
        frame.setVisible(true);

        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
                textFieldValue = textField.getText();
                frame.dispose();
                System.out.println("inside= " + textFieldValue);
            }
        });
        panel.add(button);
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return textFieldValue;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test test = new Test();
        System.out.println("outside= " + test.getValue());
    }
}

Please could anyone help on this?
By running the above code, the variable "textFieldValue" has not been assigned the value that is entered in JTextField object: textField.
Any help would be highly appreciated!

In what order is the output? "inside= ...   outside = ..." or "outside= ...   inside= ..."?

@Sither Tsering, I expect to have "inside = " first and then "outside = ".  Both printouts should be the same as the one entered in the "textField".

@Sither Tsering, I rewrote the code to make it more explicit. I expect the "inside= " to be executed first since it is inside the class constructor. When running the code, the outside was printed out first, outside= null; the inside was printed after clicking the OK button with the value entered into textField.

In the constructor, an action listener is added to the button but the action is not performed yet. When the button is clicked, it executes actionPerformed method. The actionPerformed method for the button runs asynchronously, meaning outside in main gets executed before the button is even clicked.

Note: textFieldValue gets updated after clicking the button. It's just that it was printed before it was updated. You can move that print inside. System.out.println("before = " + textFieldValue);    textFieldValue = textField.getText();    System.out.println("after = " + textFieldValue);

@Sither Tsering, my aim is to use the textFieldValue in the main() function to do something else. With this code, it is not assigned the right value as shown by the printout of "outside=". Just wonder if using a separate thread will help?

If you want to blocks other components until you get input from user, you can use JDialog instead of jFrame.
JDialog dialog = new JDialog();
...

button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        textFieldValue = textField.getText();
        System.out.println("inside = " + textFieldValue);
        dialog.dispose(); // Close dialog
    }
});

...
panel.add(button);

dialog.getContentPane().add(panel);
dialog.setSize(500, 300);
dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
dialog.setModal(true); // Make it modal to block the main thread
dialog.setVisible(true);

or one input at a time
textFieldValue = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your name: ");


many thanks for your help, using JDialog works.

The problem with your code, is in the order of execution, that is not the one that you suppose, let's see:
The first thing that is executed, is the line:
Test test = new Test();

which is in the main method, then the variable textFieldValue is created, which is followed by the execution of the constructor.
Inside the constructor, we find a small error, the line:
panel.add( button );

should be after:
frame.setVisible( true );

although it is not the source of your problem.
Let's continue with the order of execution.
In the constructor, the necessary components are created, added to their respective containers, and frame is set with the appropriate values, then the listener for button is added, finally frame is made visible (as you will notice, up to this point, the textFieldValue variable was not instantiated), and the execution of the constructor ends.
The next line to be executed is:
System.out.println( "outside= " + test.getValue() );

which is in the main method after Test test = new Test();, which, obviously, finds textFieldValue with value null, it will only change its value, when you click on button, although the execution of main is already finished, in short, whatever you need to execute after the user enters a string in textFieldValue, you must place it in a method, which must be called from the listener of button, something like:
panel.add(button);
frame.setVisible(true);
button.addActionListener( new ActionListener() {
   @Override
   public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent ae ) {
      textFieldValue = textField.getText();
      System.out.println( "inside= " + textFieldValue );
      runAction();
      frame.dispose();
   });
}

and outside the builder:
void runAction() {
   I do something();
}

I hope I have helped you.

Many thanks for your time and help. That really helps!

I am glad to have helped you :)
